# Inserting and displaying books

Tags: c++, beginner, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to write a program where you can insert and display some books (without using a database).

For doing this, I use three classes:

- `Book` - is the base class.
- `TehnicBook` and `Literature` - that will inherit some properties from `Book`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Book {
public:
    string author, title;
    bool rented;

    Book(string &author, string &title, bool rented) {
        this -> author = author;
        this -> title = title;
        this -> rented = rented;
    };
    void display(void);
};

class TehnicBook:public Book {
    int amount, RlYear;
    string language;
    TehnicBook *head, *next;
public:
    TehnicBook(string &author, string &title, bool rented, int amount, string &language, int RlYear):Book(author, title, rented) {
        head = NULL;
        this -> language = language;
        this -> amount = amount;
        this -> RlYear = RlYear;
    };
    ~TehnicBook(void) {
        delete head;
    };
    void display(void);
    void add(void);
    void dellete(string&);
};

class Literature:public Book {
    string bookType;
    Literature *head, *next;
public:
    Literature(string &author, string &title, bool rented, string &bookType):Book(author, title, rented) {
        head = NULL;
        this -> bookType = bookType;
    };
    ~Literature(void) {
        delete head;
    };
    void display(void);
    void add(void);
};

void TehnicBook::add(void) {
    string author, title, language;
    int year, amount;
    bool rented;

    cout << endl << "Author: ", cin >> author;
    cout << "Title: ", cin >> title;
    cout << "Rented? (0/1): ", cin >> rented;
    cout << "The amount of books: ", cin >> amount;
    cout << "Language: ", cin >> language;
    cout << "Release year: ", cin >> year;

    TehnicBook *p = new TehnicBook(author, title, rented, amount, language, year);
    p -> next = head;
    head = p;
}

void TehnicBook::display(void) {
    TehnicBook *p = head;
    while(p) {
        cout << "-----------------------------\n";
        cout << "Author: " << p -> author << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << p -> title << endl;
        cout << "Is " << ((p -> rented) ? "" : "not ") << "rented" << endl;
        cout << "Amount of books: " << p -> amount << endl;
        cout << "Language: " << p -> language << endl;
        cout << "Release year: " << p -> RlYear << endl;
        cout << endl;

        p = p -> next;
    }
}

void Literature::add(void) {
    string author, title, bookType;
    bool rented;

    cout << "\nAuthor: ", cin >> author;
    cout << "Title: ", cin >> title;
    cout << "Is rented? ", cin >> rented;
    cout << "Book type (hardcover/...: ", cin >> bookType;

    Literature *p = new Literature(author, title, rented, bookType);
    p -> next = head;

    head = p;
}

void Literature::display(void) {
    Literature *p = head;
    while(p) {
        cout << "\n-----------------------------\n";
        cout << "Author: " << p -> author << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << p -> title << endl;
        cout << "Is rented? " << ((p -> rented) ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
        cout << "Book type: " << p -> bookType << endl << endl;

        p = p -> next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const **argv) {

    string blank = "";
    TehnicBook *tehnicB = new TehnicBook(blank, blank, false, 0, blank, 0);
    Literature *litB = new Literature(blank, blank, false, blank);
    int opt;

    for(;;) {

        cout << "\n\n1) Add a tehnic book.\n";
        cout << "2) Display all tehnic books.\n";
        cout << "3) Add a literature book.\n";
        cout << "4) Display all literature books.\n";
        cout << "5) Exit.\n\n";

        cout << "Your option: ", cin >> opt;

        switch(opt) {
            case 1:
                tehnicB -> add();
                break;
            case 2:
                tehnicB -> display();
                break;
            case 3:
                litB -> add();
                break;
            case 4:
                litB -> display();
                break;
            case 5:
                exit(0);
            default:
                continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing this right? Any better ideas?

Comment: It doesn't seem to actually work.  When I put in "Marius Marusanici" as the author for the first book, the code simply infinitely repeats the menu.

Comment: @Edward Yep, it only works when you insert something without spaces. I think this is how **cin** works with strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Major bug: `Book::~Book` is not `virtual`. This means you have a memory leak in the following case:

  ```
  TehnicBook *tb = new TehnicBook(...);
  tb->add(...);
  Book *b = tb;
  delete tb; //<- tb->head is leaked
  ```

  If you have C++11 I recommend that every class either has a `virtual` destructor or is declared `final` such as `class Book final{...}`.
- Major design issue: You are combining `TehnicBook` with a linked list. A class should have only one responsibility: Either manage a book or manage memory, not both. At least use `std::list` or better `std::vector`. Better remove `add` from `TehnicBook` and `Literature` and put a `vector<Book>` into `main` to seperate storage and functionality.
- Similarly `add` should not use `cin` and `cout`. You are mixing user interface and class functionality. It should simply take a `TehnicBook *`. You can make a free standing function that conveniently does this, but it should not be part of `TehnicBook`.
- Similarly `display` should not use `cout`. Either make it return a `string` which you then give to `cout` or teach `cout` how to print books such as this:

  ```
  ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, TehnicBook &t){
      os << 
      os << "-----------------------------\n";
      os << "Author: " << p->author << endl;
      os << "Title: " << p->title << endl;
      os << "Is " << ((p->rented) ? "" : "not ") << "rented" << endl;
      os << "Amount of books: " << p->amount << endl;
      os << "Language: " << p->language << endl;
      os << "Release year: " << p->RlYear << endl;
      os << endl;
      return os;
  }
  ```

  Now you can do `TehnicBook book(...); cout << book;`, which is pretty neat, but more importantly you can do things like `ofstream file("test.txt"); file << book;`, so we got printing a book to a file and TCP-streams and so on for free.
- I see `void dellete(string&);` inside `TehnicBook`, but no implementation. I guess you meant to add the functionality to remove books from the list. Remove this function, it does not belong to a `TehnicBook`.
- Is `TehnicBook` supposed to be `TechnicBook` or `TechnicalBook`?
- This may be a bit over your head, but I want to at least mention it: Do not use `new` and `delete`. Ever. Instead use `make_unique`.

  ```
  TehnicBook *tehnicB = new TehnicBook(blank, blank, false, 0, blank, 0);
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  auto tehnicB = make_unique<TehnicBook>(blank, blank, false, 0, blank, 0);
  ```

  The point is that now you do not need to manage memory. Managing memory is very difficult and error prone and unnecessary. For example you forgot to clean up `tehnicB` and `litB` inside `main`. This automatically gets fixed without thinking about it with modern C++.

Comment: A book collection could be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Book>> library;` and then books could be added as `library.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Literature>("Tolstoy", "War and Peace", false, "hardcover"));`

Comment: You might also want to mention how to actually implement polymorphism.  For instance, define `virtual std::ostream &display(std::ostream &out)` in `Book` and then implement `display` in derived classes, calling `Book::display` first.  Then use it as `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Book& b) { return b.display(out); }`

Comment: @Edward Unless it is a specific question I'd rather recommend a [book](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html).

Comment: `A class should have only one responsibility`: Pattern called `"Separation of Concerns"`

Comment: `display should not use cout. Either make it return a string` Or more conveniently pass it a stream.

Comment: `The point is that now you do not need to manage memory.` Correct. So don't even dynamically allocate when `automatic` variables will do.

Answer (score 2):

Bug: you cannot enter multiple words for any of the string arguments, for example author and title. It will make more sense to read full lines there, for example:

```
cout << endl << "Author: ";
getline(cin, author);
```

Please don't use `using namespace std` (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).
This is ok though:

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
```

But the best is to not do this at all, but use explicitly `std::cout` when you need,
especially for common names like `string`, which might easily conflict with other implementations. See also [@Loki's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68219/inserting-and-displaying-books/68222?noredirect=1#comment124479_68222).

Instead of `#include <stdlib.h>`, write like this: `#include <cstdlib>`.
But actually, as [@Edward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39848/edward) pointed out,
it would be better to remove this import,
and change the single `exit(0)` statement to `return 0`.

It's unusual to put spaces around `->`. This is more common:

```
this->author = author;
```

`RlYear` is not a very good name. Use `camelCase` for variable names in general.
For this variable, `releaseYear` would be a better name.

You can simplify the constructor of `Book` like this:

```
Book(string &author, string &title, bool rented) :
    author(author), title(title), rented(rented) {}
```

Similarly, `TechnicBook` like this:

```
TehnicBook(string &author, string &title, bool rented, int amount, string &language, int RlYear) :
    Book(author, title, rented), head(NULL), language(language), amount(amount), RlYear(RlYear) {}
```

Lastly, although the title says "c++ polymorphism",
there's no example of polymorphism in this code.

Comment: @Edward `g++` cannot find `exit` without that line

Comment: True, but then that line would be better as `return 0;` anyway.

Comment: @Edward good call, updated my answer, thanks for that!

Comment: `This is ok though:` Depends: In global scope it is better (not ideal (especially string it is way too common an identifier to be put in the global namespace)). Best is to just be specific `std::cout << "Works fine\n";`

Comment: Thanks @LokiAstari, I added a comment on that to clarify.